# Videojs: remove current instance and re-initialize a new player

Tags: jquery, html, dom, video.js

I am using the videojs javascript to play video and show streaming.

I have one player (`<div id ="video-container"><video controls preload='auto' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered' id="player"></video></div>`
) and I use it for play video or for the streaming.
The initialize about the streaming is the following:

```
  initializeStreaming () {
        var html = "<video controls preload='auto' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered' id='player' ></video>";
        //$('#video-container').html('');       
        videojs('player').dispose();
        $('#player').remove();
        $('#video-container').append(html);

        var player = videojs('player', {

            techOrder: ["html5", "flash"],
            autoplay: true,
            sources: [{
              type: "application/x-mpegURL",
              src: url
            }],
        });
}
```

I remove the current player configured and I try to initilize a new player for the streaming.
In Firefox, chrome it works very well, the problem is in IE11 on windows 7 .

I have the following error:

> undefined or null reference" (row 12888). The problem seems to be the
>   variable this.player_.

Somebody can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert on this plugin, but I would say you need to `dispose()` the element before removing it from the DOM (`$('#video-container').html('');`)

Comment: Hi, It was a mistake!!! Thanks ;)